# Linux : automatically execute an sh script when switched to another user

Tags: linux, centos, mq

I am new to Linux, I have installed a vagrant virtual machine(centos)
when I do:

```
vagrant up
```

then

```
vagrant ssh  
[vagrant@acpdc1 ~]$
```

and added these two lines in `.bashrc`

```
sudo su - mqm
source /opt/mqm/bin/setmqenv -s
```

after rebooting and did :

```
vagrant reload 
vagrant ssh
```

I got the same user vagrant :

```
[vagrant@acpdc1 ~]$
```

and the second line did not take effect too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired effect you can first execute the command as the user and then switch into that user account.

Such a procedure would look like this:

```
su -c 'source /opt/mqm/bin/setmqenv -s'  - mqm
su - mqm
```

In your bashrc, the second line is never executed as the mqm user.

Comment: your second line works, but the first line su -c 'source /opt/mqm/bin/setmqenv -s'  - mqm   did not take effect

Comment: Can you add the line to the bashrc or profile of the mqm user?

Comment: There is no bashrc or profile in the mqm user home .